# Python Random Forest bad probability distribution

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distribution, random-forest

Using Scikit Random Forest classifier. I am trying to predict a binary target and getting the probabilities with.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42,class_weight=None, max_features="auto",
                            bootstrap="False", criterion='entropy')
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)   
preds = rf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

The problem is the probability distribution is somewhat weird.
[image]

As you see the bin at 0.4 is somewhat weird. I could understand short fluctuations but this is a dramatic decrease in numbers falling to that bin. 
Considering the test set is around 10M.

```
The size of bin for 0.3 is 1.7M 
The size of bin for 0.4 is 0.5M !!
The size of bin for 0.5 is 1.3M
```

How can Python Random Forest make such a hole in the prob distribution ? Any tips or thoughts on this ?

Ps: plot with bins=50
[image]

Comment: How do you create your bins? How does the histogram look like when you use something like matplotlib.pyplot.hist on the raw preds?

Comment: I am using matplotlib.pyplot.hist  and preds[:1,].hist(bins=10) , the graphs are identical

Comment: try to make a finer grained histogram, 50 bins or so.

Comment: i added with bins = 50 , the problem is different i believe. Related with RF predictions.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-calibration-plot-calibration-curve-py